# Strange values in Debugging View in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

in my app for IPhone I pass some values (timestamps) to C++ library as `int64_t`. Before it I cast values from `NSArray`, where they are stored as `double`, to `int64_t` like that in .mm file:

```
int64_t f4 = (int64_t)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

The problem you can see on the picture (see link) is, that the shown selected value of variable **f4** (left) is not the same as its printed value to the right. Further if I compare vars **f1** and **f4**, **f4** should be greater, than **f1**, concerning stored values, but it is not. Var **f1** is returned from a function inside the library and the Debugging View shows right value.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` (and all Objective-C collection classes) can only hold objects.  That means if you want to store numbers in a collection they need to be wrapped in an `NSNumber` object.  For example:

```
[arr addObject:@(number)];
```

and to retrieve the value:

```
int64_t value = [arr[index] longLongValue];
```

However to answer the question, the values you are seeing are probably the addresses of the `NSNumber` objects, not the values contained within them.